# How to linearize the product of binary variables?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, mixed-integer-programming, binary-programming

I have the following equation that I need to linearize for an integer programming problem,

$s_i$ = $x_{i-1}$*$y_i$

where $s,x,y$  are binary 
and $i ∈ ${1,2,3,4,5,6}

I've noticed that there is a general form for linearizing the product of binary  and continuous variables as mentioned here,

[Converting nonlinear constraints (product of binary and continuous variables) for linear programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154253/converting-nonlinear-constraints-product-of-binary-and-continuous-variables-fo?rq=1)

Could the same be used for binary and binary product as well?

Would appreciate any form of help for this. Thanks

Comment: See [this post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction @RobPratt! That really helps :)